# `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- midiator

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have this error loading a ruby file:
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- midiator (LoadError)

RubyGems Environment:

- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.6
- RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i686-darwin9.7.0]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:

  - ruby
  - x86-darwin-9
- GEM PATHS:

  - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - /Users/pableras/.gem/ruby/1.8
- GEM CONFIGURATION:

  - :update_sources => true
  - :verbose => true
  - :benchmark => false
  - :backtrace => false
  - :bulk_threshold => 1000

I had a lot of problems tu install rubygems and now I have problems again with midiator gem. I think something is not well configured. It is like the paths are not properly configured (Midiator gem is installed), but I do not know how to fix this.

Comment: Is it listed when you do `gem list`?

Comment: thanks it was not in the gem list. I reinstall it and it runs now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning this into an answer as it solved the problem:

Is it listed when you do `gem list`?